# how should i add the tradingview chart to my website usding python/django. i am using louisnw01/ lightweight-charts-python from github

Tags: python, django, tradingview-api, lightweight-charts

i am using the following code :

```
import pandas as pd
from lightweight_charts import Chart


def get_bar_data(symbol, timeframe):
    if symbol not in ('AAPL', 'GOOGL', 'TSLA'):
        print(f'No data for "{symbol}"')
        return pd.DataFrame()
    return pd.read_csv(f'bar_data/{symbol}_{timeframe}.csv')


def on_search(chart, searched_string):  # Called when the user searches.
    new_data = get_bar_data(searched_string, chart.topbar['timeframe'].value)
    if new_data.empty:
       return
    chart.topbar['symbol'].set(searched_string)
    chart.set(new_data)


def on_timeframe_selection(chart):  # Called when the user changes the timeframe.
    new_data = get_bar_data(chart.topbar['symbol'].value, chart.topbar['timeframe'].value)
    if new_data.empty:
       return
    chart.set(new_data, True)


def on_horizontal_line_move(chart, line):
    print(f'Horizontal line moved to: {line.price}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    chart = Chart(toolbox=True)
    chart.legend(True)

    chart.events.search += on_search

    chart.topbar.textbox('symbol', 'TSLA')
    chart.topbar.switcher('timeframe', ('1min', '5min', '30min'), default='5min',
                      func=on_timeframe_selection)

    df = get_bar_data('TSLA', '5min')
    chart.set(df)

    chart.horizontal_line(200, func=on_horizontal_line_move)

    chart.show(block=True)
```

here chart.show() gives the Python webview app but I want to integrate this chart into my own website.
I tried searching the web a lot but every time I get the Tradingview lightweight chart widget or its javascript library that the trading view provides by itself but not using the above python library.